# Waits HtmlElements

Tags: java, htmlelements

If the button doesn't exist then the test would hang for much longer than 5 seconds.

The method `findElement()` in `DefaultElementLocator` was invoked ~63 times!

The deeper the nesting of the blocks, the longer the waiting time.

Is it possible to use blocks this way in htmlElements?
What am I doing wrong?

```java
@Test
public void myTestFunc() {
    WebElement element = myPage.getMyForm()
                              .getSubForm()
                              .getButton()
                              .getWrappedElement();
    try {
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 5))
            .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public class MyPage {
    @FindBy(className = "...")
    private MyForm myForm;

    public MyPage(WebDriver driver){
        PageFactory.initElements(new HtmlElementDecorator(driver), this);
    }

    public MyForm getMyForm() {
        return myForm;
    }
}
public class MyForm extends HtmlElement {
    @FindBy(className = "...")
    private MySubForm mySubForm;

    public MySubForm getMySubForm() {
        return mySubForm;
    }
}
public class MySubForm extends HtmlElement {
    @FindBy(className = "...")
    private MyButtonWrap button;

    public MyButtonWrap getButton() {
        return button;
    }
}
public class MyButtonWrap extends Button {
    public MyButtonWrap(WebElement wrappedElement) {
        super(wrappedElement);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: i don't see the usage of 60 anywhere in your code...

Comment: It's strange...
Ok. I've launched once more and got 25 sec.
But it's too much, cause WebDriverWait would have to throw TimeoutExeption. (button doesn't exist)
I know that in HtmlElements AjaxElementlocator waiting time by default 5 sec., but the function hangs 25 sec.
And the deeper the nesting of the block, the longer the waiting time (

Comment: what's the purpose of using `WebDriverWait` in your code?

Comment: The point: to wait the apearence of the element.
I showed it for the example. Actually, wedriverwait is located in the method class MyPage.
He is needed for the appearance of the form on the page.
I want that the last user in the test doesn't't think about "how" to wait this appearance, but just points the time "seconds".
Could you advice me any best practices?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to the implicit wait which is set to a default of 5 seconds. See [this issue](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements/issues/111) for more details.

What I think is happening is that when you try to get the wrappedElement:

```java
myPage.getMyForm().getSubForm().getButton().getWrappedElement();
```

it is implicitly waiting for 5s for each `@FindBy`.

Try putting print statements and seeing where the time is being spent, e.g.:

```java
public void myTestFunc() {
    System.out.println("start");
    element = myPage.getMyForm().getSubForm().getButton().getWrappedElement();
    System.out.println("got element");
    try {
        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 5)).until(visibilityOf(element));
        System.out.println("Finished waiting successfully");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```